# How to code for Smartwatch 2

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-galaxy-gear

I don't know how to port my app from a Samsung phone base to a Galaxy gear base and get it to run on my watch. I need to know how to connect my app to the watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect your Phone with a Wear you will need to set up a DataAPI.

There is a really good library called [Teleport.lib](https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport) which shortens the code a lot. If you want to avoid using this library you can follow the instruction which are given in this [Android Wear](http://youtu.be/jbbKCfCIyFA?t=35m53s) talk.